# What does "won medal up" and "won medal down" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Two phrases "won medal up" and "won medal down" is from the song "Come out ye black and tans" and I truly can't understand it :(

"Come out you black and tans,
Come out and fight me like a man,
Show your wife how you won MEDALS DOWN in Flanders;
Tell her how the IRA made you run like hell away,
From the green and lovely lanes of Killeshandra. "

"Oh! Come out you British Huns,
Come out and fight without your guns,
Show your wife how you won MEDALS UP in Derry;
You murdered sixteen men and you'll do the same again,
So get out of here and take your bloody army".

Comment: Since no one else can understand it without further context, please [edit] your post to include as much of the actual lyrics as needed to make sense of these expressions. My guess is that "medal-up" and "medal-down" (note my punctuation) are orientations, but what that has to do with winning is beyond me.

Comment: The preposition (up/down) goes with the place (Flanders/Derry"), not the medals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for the lyrics, I found this line

> Show your wife how you won medals **down in Flanders**

at
[lyrics.com song](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/1183373/Wolfe+Tones/Come+Out+Ye+Black+and+Tans)

The phrase means simply "toward the south in Flanders".

I didn't find "won medals up", although it might appear in another version of the lyrics.

Added 11/28 You've added lyrics that contain "...won medals up in Derry..."; that usage is analogous to "down in Flanders", so it probably means "to the North in Derry".

Comment: Indeed: Derry/Londonderry is close to the north coast of Ireland.

Comment: And one can win hands down down in Down.